# How to enable php exif extension?

Tags: php

I am using wındows (plesk) hosting. Can someone tell me how to enable php libaries there. My final purpose is to fix the rotation problem while uploading from mobile camera. I guess i need imagemagick or exif extensions to be activated. Should i just create an ini file (which one? php.ini or user.ini) and place it to webroot. I tried to do so but it didn't work. My hosting help center is so hard to connect and comunicate.